# How can I find exact matching records from two different table which doesn't have any id column using SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have to find matching records and non-matching records as well from two different table.
suppose I have two tables,

**table 1: manufacturer_detail**

column: Manufacturer_name

```
   Manufacturer_name
   ABB, INC
   ABB PHARMA
   FIBER INC
```

**table 2: Contractor_detail**

column:Contractor_name

```
    Contractor_name
    ABB, INC
    OBS COMPANY
    FIBER
```

**Expected Result**

```
    Matching_Records
    ABB, INC
```

so here I want to find if any Manufacturer_name is matching with Contractor_name or not? so Basically I want all Manufacturer_name which are matching with Contractor_name as a result and vise-versa like if I wanted see how many of my manufacturer are contractor as well then give me matching list otherwise give me non_matching list.
I am doing this exercise in Snowflake.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Matching on names like this is normally risky unless your data is very well cleansed/mastered. If it isn't, it would probably be good practise to remove case differences, spaces, punctuation, etc. before trying to match. Even then matching is not guaranteed e.g. one  instance of a name includes Inc./Ltd. and one doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT j.Manufacture_name,
       CASE 
           WHEN j.Contractor_name IS NULL THEN 0
           ELSE 1 
       END as "matching"
FROM ( 
       SELECT m.Manufacture_name, c.Contractor_name 
       FROM manufacture_detail m
       LEFT JOIN contractor_detail c
       ON c.Contractor_name = m.Manufacturer_name) j;
```

-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-EDIT
-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-

This script's output will match the expected output you have added to your original question:

```
SELECT m.Manufacture_name 
FROM manufacture_detail m
JOIN contractor_detail c
ON c.Contractor_name = m.Manufacturer_name;
```

A simple inner join will do the magic in this case.

Comment: So the **matching**  column with 0 output consider as non-matching records?

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea. you can replace the LEFT JOIN statement with RIGHT JOIN in order to have the same result for Contractor_name. I'm editing my answer so it will include a result which will match the expected result you have added to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

"My Koryto" gave a good answer. Adding this one to match the desired output - plus testing data:

```sql
WITH manufacturer_detail AS (
    SELECT value Manufacturer_name
    FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(SPLIT('ABB, INC|ABB PHARMA|FIBER INC', '|')))
), Contractor_detail AS (
    SELECT value Contractor_name
    FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(SPLIT('ABB, INC|OBS COMPANY|FIBER', '|')))
)

SELECT Manufacturer_name AS Matching_Records
FROM manufacturer_detail a
JOIN contractor_detail b
ON a.Manufacturer_name=b.Contractor_name;
```

[image]

(the solution involves just a basic SQL JOIN)